# After user login, how do you ask user for permissions?

Tags: support, authentication, c#, .net

For an app on Windows Phone, I'm missing the page after you enter your login credentials and click submit.  When I debug on my device, after I log in I obtain the correct response Uri with access token.  But it ends there.  It does not ask if I want to give the app permissions or not.

It is supposed to show what username you are logged in as and also provide two buttons to either accept or deny the application access. (see image below)

I'm following the same login procedure as Facebook client.

[image]

Comment: have you got any code?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It ended up not being an issue with the code, it was the Uri was missing scope - see my answer below.

Comment: so problem solved then?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry yes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to add the scope in the authentication url according to this document
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope

1.Send a user to https://stackexchange.com/oauth, with these query string parameters

◦client_id

**◦scope (details)**

◦redirect_uri - must be under an apps registered domain

◦state - optional